# google calendar change event created by text

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using google api php client library to create event in one of my calendar which is shared by other users as well, the issue is I can't change the the field "Created by " in event detail, Is it possible to change that text? pls check my attached screenshot for more info.[image]

2nd issue is notifications are not working, when a new event created in google calendar no notification sent to user, is there any other setting or I should changed in api parameters?

```
$objCalendar    =   new  \Helper\GoogleCalendar();
$colorid = 8;
                if($item->status == 'Pending'){
                    $colorid = 6;
                }elseif($item->status == 'Working'){
                    $colorid = 9;
                }elseif($item->status == 'Completed'){
                    $colorid = 10;
                }
                $event = array(
                            //'params'=>array('sendNotifications'=>true),
                            'sendNotifications'=>true,
                            'summary' => $item->subject,
                            'description' => $item->comment,
                            'colorId' => $colorid,
                            'start' => array(
                                'date' => $item->due_date
                            ),
                            'end' => array(
                                'date' => $item->due_date
                            ),
                            'attendees' => $admin_user_emails,
                            'reminders' => array(
                                'useDefault' => FALSE,
                                'overrides' => array(
                                    array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                                    array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                                ),
                            ),
                        );
$objCalendar->addEvent($event);
```

Helper/GoogleCalendar.php

```
 function add_event($e){
    $calName = 'xyz@group.calendar.google.com';
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($e);
     $optParams = array('sendNotifications' => true);
            $createdEvent = $service->events->insert($calName, $event);
            $service->events->patch($calName ,$createdEvent->getId(), $event, $optParams );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. created by is set when you insert it to my knowledge its going to be the users email address not their name unless you have the user added in your google people on your account there is no way for Google to get the persons name
2. do an [events patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) after you create your event and add the reminders then i remember there being an issue with adding them all at once.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply.. can you pls tell me how should I set user email  in created by when insert function called?